# Is there an analog of Cech complex for local cohomology over noncommutative rings?

Tags: homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a noetherian ring, and let $I\subseteq A$ be an ideal.

Suppose $I$ is generated by $a_1,\dots,a_n$.

Let $M$ be a left $A$-module.

If $A$ is commutative, then one can compute the derived $I$-torsion of $M$ by:

$H^n_I(M) \cong H^n(C(a_1,\dots,a_n)\otimes_A M)$, where $C(a_1,\dots,a_n)$ is the Cech complex associated to that sequence.

I would like to know if a similar result holds over non-commutative rings?

What are possible references for this?

Comment: I was going to recommend Rotman's Homological Algebra book, but I can't guarantee it includes the noncommutative version or not (been too long since I've looked at it.)

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking: What is the "cohomology over a noncommutative ring"? Cohomology of what and with what coefficients?